# Scala test case with URL

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a case class that has a URL field:

```
    import java.net.URL

    case class A(a: URL)
```

I am writing a test case, which has follwoing assertion.
result.url is obtained from case class.

```
result.url should equal(new java.net.URL("https://hostpath/"))
```

result.url prints me :

https://hostpath/

My test case fails saying they are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **new** keyword it createa all together a new object and  it would fail depending on the underlying URLs's equals implementation

```
result.url.toString should equal(new java.net.URL("https://hostpath/").toString)
```

If you take a look at URL's equals method implementation it looks something like this and is not as simple as comparing the textual URL portion.

```
protected boolean equals(URL u1, URL u2) {
        String ref1 = u1.getRef();
        String ref2 = u2.getRef();
        return (ref1 == ref2 || (ref1 != null && ref1.equals(ref2))) &&
               sameFile(u1, u2);
    }

protected boolean equals(URL u1, URL u2) {
        String ref1 = u1.getRef();
        String ref2 = u2.getRef();
        return (ref1 == ref2 || (ref1 != null && ref1.equals(ref2))) &&
               sameFile(u1, u2);
    }
```